# Do calls to Schema.getGlobalDescribe() not run in system context in classes declared as without sharing?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a user profile with everything disabled except for `API Only` and `API Enabled`. This user profile is given access to a set of classes that have REST services defined within them.

I am seeing very strange behavior when calling `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`. I receive a different response depending on which class I call that method from, even if all of the classes are defined the same way. Here's a simplified version of the problem:

```
global without sharing class WebServiceClass {

  {
    System.debug(WebServiceClass.fieldsContainName()); // THIS RETURNS TRUE
    System.debug(UtilityClass.fieldsContainName()); //THIS RETURNS FALSE!
  }

  global static Boolean fieldsContainName() {
    System.debug(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('contact').getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet().contains('name'));
  }
}

global without sharing class UtilityClass {
  global static Boolean fieldsContainName() {
    System.debug(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('contact').getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet().contains('name'));
  }
}
```

Why would this be?

Answer (score 2):

`without sharing` only affects sharing (i.e. which rows you can see), it has no affect on system mode vs user mode. Typically only triggers run in system mode, other apex entry points like web services run in user mode.

Comment: Does `without sharing` cause the class to run without sharing but in user mode instead of system mode? I don't understand why I could run SOQL statements and retrieve any column (which suggests that the class is running in system mode), but if I run the same query using `Database.query()`, some columns don't return? Why would that be?

Comment: sharing and system mode are 2 orthogonal states. sharing only affects which rows you can system, user vs system mode affects which objects & fields you can see.

Comment: can you post a specific example of where you see a difference, dynamic soql should be the same as a regular inline query.

Comment: There is definitely a difference. The simple example added above describes what I'm seeing.

Comment: Is this Apex Rest, or Apex Soap services ?

Comment: It's Apex Rest. I figured out that the issue is with `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` and updated the question. I'm still stumped by the permissions issue on this one...

Comment: what does the generated query look like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8717/discussion-between-sean-devine-and-superfell)

Answer (score 2):

`Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` seems to behave in unexpected ways when the user does not have access to the class that contains the call (even if the class is running in system mode). The fix is to add the user's profile to the list that have access to the class in question. That fixes the issue. I believe that this is a bug in `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`.

Based on [this blog post](http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/getting-dynamic-apex-to-work-in-managed-applications/), it seems as though there may be other funny behaviors related to `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` that you should watch out for too.